# Need to display javascript variable as title without space

Tags: javascript

I have a written a javascript which will return the value in the variable, in the title property.

It is not returning the values with spaces, when i execute the below code it is returning the last value as 'ashok' instead of 'ashok sensiple'

```
var ltenantName = 'Sensiple,new-tenant-001,tenant-new,Tenant_1208,ashok sensiple'; 

var ltenantNameLength = '<div style="cursor:Pointer" title='
+ ltenantName
+'>' 
+ ltenantName.split(',').length
+'</div>';

return ltenantNameLength;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML attribute values containing spaces must be quoted.

You are generating the `title` attribute without quotes around the value.

Your code:

```js
var ltenantName = 'Sensiple,new-tenant-001,tenant-new,Tenant_1208,ashok sensiple'; 

var ltenantNameLength = '<div style="cursor:Pointer" title='
+ ltenantName
+'>' 
+ ltenantName.split(',').length
+'</div>';

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ltenantNameLength));
```

As you can see `sensiple` is a **new attribute** and not part of the value of the `title` attribute.

Add quotes:

```js
var ltenantName = 'Sensiple,new-tenant-001,tenant-new,Tenant_1208,ashok sensiple'; 

var ltenantNameLength = '<div style="cursor:Pointer" title="'
+ ltenantName
+'">' 
+ ltenantName.split(',').length
+'</div>';

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ltenantNameLength));
```

Better yet, don't try to mash strings together in JS to make HTML:

```js
var ltenantName = 'Sensiple,new-tenant-001,tenant-new,Tenant_1208,ashok sensiple';

var ltenantNameLength = document.createElement('div');
// This normally indicates a link. If you want a link, why not use <a>?
ltenantNameLength.style.cursor = "pointer";
ltenantNameLength.title = ltenantName;
ltenantNameLength.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(
    ltenantName.split(',').length
  )
);

document.body.appendChild(ltenantNameLength);
```